# Медленная аутентификация со Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

При первом запросе на аутентификацию приходится ждать очень продолжительное время.  Есть подозрения, что причиной тому Spring Security.  Часть кода представлю ниже,если понадобиться доп. информация я прикреплю ниже.

```
<security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:password-encoder hash="sha"/>
            <security:jdbc-user-service
                    data-source-ref="dataSource"
                    users-by-username-query="SELECT eMail AS username, password, true AS enabled FROM user WHERE eMail=?"
                    authorities-by-username-query="SELECT eMail, role AS authority FROM user WHERE eMail=?" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.epam.testsystem.special.CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <constructor-arg value="RealmName" />
    </bean> 

   <security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config='true'>
        <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="customBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/#/teacherdashboard" access="hasRole('ROLE_TEACHER')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/#/dashboard" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/users/create" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/authentication/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/users/getCurrentProfile" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER','ROLE_OPERATOR','ROLE_TEACHER')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/users/changeCurrentProfile" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER','ROLE_OPERATOR','ROLE_TEACHER')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/users/changeRole" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/">
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </security:session-management>
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>
```

Какие могут причины тому ? Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Может нужно как-то особенно настраивать его или еще что-то? Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Подключите к проекту log4j. Поставьте уровень отладки - debug и вывод на консоль. Запустите проект. Выполните проблемное действие. Посмотрите на каком участке происходит подвисание.  Может быть у вас пинг до базы такой. Может пул так инициализируется. Или хэш долго считается. По конфигу тут не угадаешь.

Comment: enzo, спасибо, сейчас попробую